# How to select option in Angular JS with object?

Tags: angularjs

There is object:

```
   $scope.type = {
        1 : 'Inside',
        2 : 'Outside'
    };
```

HTML `ng-options:`

```
 <select ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in type" ng-model="selectedType"></select>
```

I tried:

```
$scope.selectedType = (UserGlobalService.type == 1) ? $scope.records[1] : $scope.records[2];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Edited my answer a bit

This is how I would do it:

```
$scope.types = [
   { id: 1, name: 'Inside' },
   { id: 2, name: 'Outside' }];

$scope.selectedType = $scope.type[0];
```

HTML:

```
<select ng-options="t.name for t in types" ng-model="selectedType"></select>
```

Here's Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/uyP5EeOUTQb7n1ymsFuB

Comment: This does not work for me. select list is empty. I get still empty select

Comment: Also instead `$scope.selectedType = type[0];` must be `$scope.selectedType = $scope.type[0];`

Comment: When I select element from list I need change `$scope.selectedType` on selected index

Comment: I changed my answer and added a Plunker.

Answer (score 2):

Hi this would solve your problem

Index.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app='myApp'>
    <head>

        <title>My AngularJS App</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Modules -->
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller ='MainController'>
        <div>

            <select class="form-control" >
            <!-- <option ng-value= "{{item}}" >{{item}}</option> -->
            <option ng-repeat="option in type" value="{{option.value}}" ng-selected="type.value == option.value">{{option.value}}
            </option>

        </select>               
        </div>

    </body>
```

And your JS should be like this.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.type = [{
               "id" : 1,
               "value" : "Inside"
             },{
                "id" : 2,
               "value" : "Outside"
            }];        
    }
])
```

Comment: I need select first element in select, not disabled

Comment: I need select first element from `$scope.type`

Comment: Hello @Hamed I have updated the code as per requirement.